# Access HTML classes from javascript text templates

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, templates

```html
<!-- UPLOAD TEMPLATE -->
  <script id="template-upload" type="text/x-tmpl">
   {% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
    <tr class="template-upload fade">
     <td class="name"><span>{%=file.name%}</span></td>
     <td class="size right"><span>{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span></td>
     {% if (file.error) { %}
      <td class="error" colspan="2"><span class="label label-important">Error</span> {%=file.error%}</td>
     {% } else if (o.files.valid && !i) { %}
      <td>
       <div class="progress progress-success progress-striped active nomargin" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow="0"><div class="bar" style="width:0%;"></div></div>
      </td>
      <td></td>
      <td > 
       <span class="start"> 
       {% if (!o.options.autoUpload) { %}
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-mini">
         <i class="icon-upload icon-white"></i>
         <span>Start</span>
        </button>
       </span>
       <span class="cancel">
        <button class="btn btn-warning btn-mini">
         <i class="icon-ban-circle icon-white"></i>
         <span>Cancel</span>
        </button>
       </span>


       {% } %}
      </td>
     {% } else { %}
      <td colspan="2"></td>
     {% } %}
     {% if (!o.files.valid && !i) { %}
      <td class="cancel">
       <button class="btn btn-warning btn-mini">
        <i class="icon-ban-circle icon-white"></i>
        <span>Cancel</span>
       </button>
      </td>
     {% } %}
    </tr>
   {% } %}
   </script>
```

How can I access classes like "name", "size", "start" etc from above template using jquery?
In short how do I access DOM elements from text templates using jquery?

I want to use some jquery code like 
$(".start").innerHTML blah.. blah...

Answer (score 0):

use like this

```
<select id="dist_eng" onchange="changeDistrict(this.value)">
  <c:choose>
    <c:when test="${not empty distList}">
      <option value="0" selected="true">--------Select Your District---------</option>
      <c:forEach var="d" items="${distList}" >
      </c:forEach>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
      <option value="0">No District Found</option>
    </c:otherwise>
  </c:choose>
</select
```

and form here you can easily ise the id or class attribute in jquery or javascript.